# putting a number in a hollow shape

Tags: c

I want to put number that can be one,two,three,four and so forth digits in the shape. Nonetheless, extra spaces is shifted. Besides, center is shifted. I trying different ways,however,i can't. How can i fix the problem. Thank you for all appreciated answer.

output example is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kozr1.png

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Function Prototypes */
int countNumber(int number);

int main() {

    int n;                          /* number to put in the center of the shape     */
    int column, row;                /* take values of column and row via user       */
    int columnCount, rowCount;      /* count number of column and row               */
    int i;                          /* count how many spaces remained               */

    printf("Enter column:\n>");
    scanf("%d",&column);
    printf("\nEnter row:\n>");
    scanf("%d",&row);
    printf("\nEnter number for center:\n>");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    if((10<column && column<40) && (10<row && row<40)){
    for (columnCount = 0; columnCount < column; columnCount++) {

        for (rowCount = 0; rowCount < row; rowCount++) {

            /* Middle Row */
            if (columnCount == column/2) {
                printf("#");

                for (i = 0; i < ((row*2-3)-countNumber(n))/2;i++)
                    printf(" ");

                printf("%d", n);   

                for (i = 0; i < ((row*2-3)-countNumber(n))/2;i++)
                    printf(" ");

                    printf("#");
                break;              
            }

            if (columnCount==0 || columnCount==column-1 || rowCount==0 || rowCount==row-1)
                printf("# ");
            else
                printf("  ");

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    }
        else
            printf("Please enter value btw 10-40");
    return 0;
}
/* Function */
int countNumber(int number) {

    int count;

    for(count=0;0<number;count++)   /* the number how many decimal places have */
            number/=10;

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Please add plain text output as such in your post. Having this as an image does not add anything useful.

Comment: trivally debuggable. don't tell me you don't know what's causing it.

Comment: note: `column` as *outer* loop doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work!

It still has a small margin of error but I try to solve it

```
/*Import*/
#include <stdio.h>

/*Function Prototyp*/
int countNumber(int number);

int main() {

    /*Variable*/
    int number, column, row;
    int columnCount, rowCount;
    int i;

    printf("Enter column:\n>");
    scanf("%d",&column);
    printf("\nEnter row:\n>");
    scanf("%d",&row);
    printf("\nEnter number for center:\n>");
    scanf("%d",&number);


    for (columnCount = 0; columnCount < column; columnCount++) {

        for (rowCount = 0; rowCount < row; rowCount++) {

            //Middle Row
            if (columnCount == column/2) {
                printf("*");

                for (i = 0; i < ((row*2-3)-countNumber(number))/2;i++)
                    printf(" ");

                printf("%d", number);

                for (i = 0; i < ((row*2-3)-countNumber(number))/2;i++)
                    printf(" ");

                if (countNumber(number % 2 == 0))
                    printf(" *");
                else
                    printf("*");
                break;
            }

            if (columnCount==0 || columnCount==column-1 || rowCount==0 || rowCount==row-1)
                printf("* ");
            else
                printf("  ");

        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;
}

int countNumber(int number) {

    int count;

    for (count = 0; number > 0; count++)
        number = number / 10;

    return count;
}
```

Comment: 1. "column" and "row" are the reverse of what's expected. (The OP also got it wrong.) 2. `if (countNumber(number % 2 == 0))` has misplaced parentheses (and it works only by chance, since `countNumber` returns the wrong count for the value `0`!). (2a. Add 1 to one of the `(row*2-3)-countNumber(number)` before the division so you don't need it.) 3. (Minor) the input can be a negative number; mentioned only because a small change in `countNumber` will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

this one works with any number

```
#include <stdio.h>
int digits(int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;n;i++,n=n/10);
    return i; 
    }
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int column,row;
    int n,cnt;

    printf("Enter column: ");
    scanf("%d",&column);
    printf("Enter row: ");
    scanf("%d",&row);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    cnt=digits(n);

    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<column;j++)
        {
            if(i==0 || i==(row-1) || j==0 || j==(column-1))
                printf("*");
            else if((i==(row/2)) && (j==((column-cnt)/2)))
            {
                printf("%d",n);
                j=j+(cnt-1);
            }
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your appreciate, unfortunently, what can we do if the n has more than one digit ?

Comment: i thought you were concerned about the space allignment in middle row, so i just corrected your program little. if you want more numbers inside the rectangle, then you must specify that in which pattern you want.

Comment: Look carefully at what happens when the number is longer than a single digit. It was part of the OPs problem.